# Salesforce CPQ Document Output Format

Tags: cpq

I found that article
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_allow_user_output_format.htm&type=5
I don't think this guide is updated. I can't find any way how to enable changing output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is apparently not complete. The answer to your question is at the end of https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000E0NMQA0:

"Again you may need to add this field to the user page layout."

The field exists in the user object, but it is not visible in the layout.

Comment: Thank you very much.